# Compare arrays together with different array types

Tags: xcode, swift

I want to compare if 2 arrays are equal, here is my code:

```
  var letteronloc = [String]();
      letteronloc.append("test")
  let characters = Array("test")


   if(letteronloc == characters) {

    }
```

but i have an error: could not find an overload for == that accepts the supplied arguments

I think its because the arrays are not equal, because the second array is not an string array. But how can i fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compare arrays in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567736/compare-arrays-in-swift)

Comment: @IcaroNZ no it's not, because i know how to compare them. the only problem is the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`let characters = Array("test")` treats the string as a *sequence*
(of characters) and creates an array by enumerating the elements of the sequence.
Therefore `characters` is an array of four `Character`s, 
the same that you would get with

```
let characters : [Character] = ["t", "e", "s", "t"]
```

So you have two arrays of different element types and that's why
you cannot compare them with `==`.

If you want an array with a single string "test" then write it as

```
let characters = ["test"]
```

and you can compare both arrays without problem.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to specify the type of the second array:

```
var letteronloc = [String]();
letteronloc.append("test")
let characters: [String] = Array(arrayLiteral: "test")

if (letteronloc == characters) {

}
```