# Array comparison on Swift not working as expected

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, comparison

I've got a class `Email`:

```
import SwiftyJSON

class Email: NSObject {

    required init?(JSON jsonObject: AnyObject) {
        let emailJsonObject = JSON(jsonObject)

        self.email = emailJsonObject["emailaddress"].stringValue
        self.emailType = emailJsonObject["emailtype"].stringValue
    }

   var email: String
   var emailType: String

}

func == (lhs: Email, rhs: Email) -> Bool {
    return lhs.email == rhs.email && lhs.emailType == rhs.emailType
}
```

Now if I have two `Arrays`:

```
let newEmails = emailsJsonObjects.map({ return Email(JSON: $0)! }).sort({ $0.0.email < $0.1.email })

let currentEmails = (self.emails as! [Email]).sort({ $0.0.email < $0.1.email })
```

Both have one element, and they have the same `email` and `emailType`, here's what I've got by comparing them:

```
(lldb) po newEmails.count
1

(lldb) po currentEmails.count
1

(lldb) po newEmails == currentEmails
false

(lldb) po newEmails[0] == currentEmails[0]
true
```

Am I missing something? Are the comparisons different?

Comment: `newEmails == currentEmails` asks if the two arrays are the same array which, presumably they aren't.  `newEmails[0] == currentEmails[0]` asks if the Email at index 0 in `newEmails` is the same as the Email at index 0 in `currentEmails`.

Comment: Paulw11: I thought that too, but according to this (http://stackoverflow.com/a/27580740), it actually runs through all the array elements. And I did some testing in a Playground and it actually works as expected, it's just not working in this case.

Comment: Perhaps it is just the debugger then.

Comment: When you run the code for real (i.e. not in the debugger) does it work correctly (return `true`) or fail (return `false`)?

Comment: @Paulw11: it's not the debugger, my code is reporting the same thing.

Comment: @RoboticCat: it doesn't, I have the same result as the debugger.

Comment: I've just been checking my understanding on `NSHipster`'s article on Swift Comparison Protocols: http://nshipster.com/swift-comparison-protocols/ .Do you need to make the `Email` class `Equatable` as well?

Comment: @RoboticCat I tried making Email Equatable in a playground but got an error saying that it already conforms to Equatable (through NSObject). That's why I chose to override isEqual instead.

Comment: So basically, if the `Email` class does not need to be a subclass of `NSObject` it should follow the `Equatable` protocol instead. So it follows then that making a Swift class follow the `NSObject` protocol introduces possible side-effects. Interesting. Thanks for the info @JeremyP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that, because your objects inherit from `NSObject` the array is using `isEqual()` to do the comparison of array elements. Add the following override to your class definition

```
override func isEqual(object: AnyObject?) -> Bool
{
    if let rhs = object as? Email
    {
        return self.email == rhs.email && self.emailType == rhs.emailType
    }
    return false
}
```

And it should all be fine.

Comment: Interesting: so the `==` function is not mapped to `isEqual:` in the runtime. I did not know that. I was wondering if it was something to do with `reference` types vs `value` types though. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @RoboticCat In a sense it is. The default `isEqual` compares references and that is what happens if you don't override it.

Comment: That was it! Wow so weird. As @RoboticCat mentioned, making a Swift class subclass `NSObject` introduces side-effects. Interesting. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @dccarmo If you think about it, in Objective-C, overriding `isEqual:` would have been obvious. It's a bit obscure here because of the implicit casting that is going on.