# Binary operator '!=' cannot be applied to two '[[String]]' operands

Tags: arrays, swift, binary-operators

I have an array of arrays and need to filter out one of the specific arrays in it. However, when using the following code, I get the issue "Binary operator '!=' cannot be applied to two '[[String]]' operands".

```
var arrayOfArrays = [[[String]]]()
var specificArray = [[String]]()

arrayOfArrays = arrayOfArrays.filter{$0 != specificArray}
```

I think this used to work like half a year ago...

Comment: what is the data type of specificArray?

Comment: specificArray is an array of an array of strings while arrayOfArrays is more like an array of arrays of arrays.

Comment: `specificArray` is Array<Array<String>> while `arrayOfArrays` is Array<Array<Array<String>>>

Comment: boolean operator only works on Array<String> I guess.

Comment: Look at this answer about comparing arrays
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567736/compare-arrays-in-swift

Comment: Thank you for the responses. Hunaid, I ran into that post when I was researching my issue but had not managed to find an appropriate solution to my issue with it. Am I missing something?

Comment: @JulianLee I think having an `Array<Array<Array<String>>>` in your code is very likely a sign something is wrong with your code. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to store an array of strings in categories which can be arranged into several larger categories and put into a single, accessible array. Is there a more efficient way to carry this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, [Swift Arrays don't conform to Equatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567736/compare-arrays-in-swift) so `[[T]] != [[T]]` does not work because it requires `[T]` to be Equatable. You could use [`elementsEqual(_:by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/2853785-elementsequal) instead, which allows comparing elements using a custom equality function, without being Equatable:

```
arrayOfArrays = arrayOfArrays.filter { !$0.elementsEqual(specificArray, by: ==) }
```

(Note: Thanks to [SE-0143 "*Conditional conformances*"](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0143-conditional-conformances.md), this workaround is no longer needed once Swift 4 is released.)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I see the part where I was confused regarding the other post, thank you for the explanation!