# How to remove dictionary[String:AnyObject] for array using filter function in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

```
var globalCountArray = [AnyObject]()
var assetDictionary = [String:AnyObject]()
globalCountArray.append(assetDictionary as AnyObject)
```

How to filter dictionary  using Anyobject array? I have tried this.

```
  globalCountArray = globalCountArray.filter {$0     as AnyObject != dict }
```

But I got error

Binary operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'AnyObject' and '[String : AnyObject]'"

Comment: `globalCountArray.filter {$0 as? [String: AnyObject] != dict }`?

Comment: why AnyObject array? You should specify type of array if it's a array having dictionaries then it should be var globalCountArray: [[String: Any]] = [[:]]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by filter? Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Check this :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42948755/binary-operator-cannot-be-applied-to-two-string-operands

Comment: if i change  globalCountArray: [[String: Any]] = [[:]]  like this then i got Binary operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type '[String : Any]' and '[String : AnyObject]'

Comment: Why use different type and try casting? Cant u have your array type as `[String: AnyObject]` or atleast `Any`?

Comment: Do you want to filter array to contain only dictionaries of type [String:Any] or you want to filter array for a particular dictionary?

Comment: particular dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this

```
    var globalCountArray = [AnyObject]()
    var assetDictionary = [String:AnyObject]()
    globalCountArray.append(assetDictionary as AnyObject)
    let dict = [String:AnyObject]()




    globalCountArray = globalCountArray.filter({ (obj) -> Bool in

        if obj is[String:AnyObject] {

            return (obj as! [String:AnyObject]) != dict 


        }
        return false
    })
```

--------- OR You can achieve the same via ----------

```
globalCountArray = globalCountArray.filter({ (obj) -> Bool in

            if obj is[String:AnyObject] {

                return (obj as! [String:AnyObject]) == dict 


            }
            return true
        })
```

You need to add this method to outside your class definition.

```
public func !=(lhs: [String: AnyObject], rhs: [String: AnyObject] ) -> Bool {
    return !NSDictionary(dictionary: lhs).isEqual(to: rhs)
}

 public func ==(lhs: [String: AnyObject], rhs: [String: AnyObject] ) -> Bool {
    return NSDictionary(dictionary: lhs).isEqual(to: rhs)
}
```

Comment: i got this errror     'AnyObject' is not convertible to '[String : AnyObject]'; did you mean to use 'as!' to force downcast?

Comment: i have tried this but i got error  Binary operator '!=' cannot be applied to two '[String : AnyObject]' operands

Comment: Oh i Actually made for "==" for now, I have updated it for "!="

Comment: It will not deleted the  same object  but delete the other object . example suppose there are two dictionary A,B  and i want to delete A but in actual it will delete B not A.. i think != is required.. But it gives error

Comment: I have used the "!=" as per your question. You need to choose "==" for this.

Comment: Binary operator '!=' cannot be applied to two '[String : AnyObject]' operands

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159055/discussion-between-sucharu-hasija-and-akshay).

Answer (score 0):

You can write an extension for Dictionary:

```
extension Dictionary where Key: ExpressibleByStringLiteral, Value: AnyObject {
    func isEqual(_ dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) -> Bool {
        return NSDictionary(dictionary: dictionary).isEqual(to: self)
    }

    func isNotEqual(_ dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) -> Bool {
        return !NSDictionary(dictionary: dictionary).isEqual(to: self)
    }
}
```

Then you can compare `[String: AnyObject]` dictionaries with:

```
FirstDictionary.isEqual(SecondDictionary)
FirstDictionary.isNotEqual(SecondDictionary)
```

In your case:

```
var globalCountArray = [AnyObject]()
var assetDictionary = [String:AnyObject]()
globalCountArray.append(assetDictionary as AnyObject)

globalCountArray = globalCountArray.filter { (($0 as! [String: AnyObject]).isNotEqual(assetDictionary)) }
```