# Remove duplicates from a multi-dimensional array

Tags: arrays, swift, value-type, equatable

I wrote the following extension to remove duplicates from my Array.

```
extension Array where Element : Equatable{

    func removeDups() -> [Element]{
        var result = [Element]()

        for element in self{
            if !result.contains(element){
                result.append(element)
            }
        }

        return result
    }
}
```

**Linear Array**

```
let linearArr = [1,2,2,3]
linearArr.removeDups() // [1,2,3] works well!
```

**Multi dimensional Array**

```
let multiDimArr : [[Int]] = [[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2 ,4]]
multiDimArr.removeDups() // Error!
```

> Type [Int] does not conform to Equatable

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27568162/5175709). And the answer says Array comparisons using `==` should work. It doesn't work all the time:

**Works**

```
if (["1", "2"] == ["1", "2"]){
    print("true")
}
```

**Doesn't work**

```
if ([1, 2] == [1, 2]){ // ERROR!
    print("true")
}
```

> Ambiguous use of operator '=='

This is peculiar. I can compare Array of `String`s but can't compare Array of `Int`s.

I also saw [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567736/compare-arrays-in-swift/27568162#comment43574159_27568162):

*The reason `myArray1 == myArray2` is that `NSObject` conforms to Equatable, calling `-[equals:]` to conduct the test*

Not sure if the ☝️ comment is still valid.

To summarize:

- Are arrays equatable? Can I compare them using `==`
- Why is it different for comparing Array of `String`s vs. Array of `Int`s
- How can I remove duplicates from a multi-dimensional array?

I'm currently working with `Swift 4.0.2`

Comment: I'm not sure but I think Swift 4.1 adds support for `[Int]` being `Equatable`.

Comment: Looks like it @rmaddy https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0185-synthesize-equatable-hashable.md

Comment: @rmaddy is correct – in Swift 4.1, `Array<Element>` conforms to `Equatable` when `Element` conforms to `Equatable`, so `multiDimArr.removeDups()` will compile in 4.1 provided you relax your (currently over-constrained) extension to `where Element : Equatable`.

Comment: The fact that `[1, 2] == [1, 2]` doesn't compile is the bug [SR-5944](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5944), the compiler is considering it to be ambiguous due to `==` overloads for `IndexSet` and `IndexPath` (both of which are `ExpressibleByArrayLiteral`). But Swift should default an array literal to `Array` though, resolving the ambiguity. Saying `[1, 2] as [Int] == [1, 2]` or not importing `Foundation` resolves the issue.

Comment: @Hamish interesting. About your 2nd comment. Both your solutions work on `4.0.2`. About your 1st comment. _provided you relax your (currently over-constrained_. I actually intended it to be `Equatable`. (I'll edit it now). There is no reason to have it be for `Comparable`. And is this any different for Swift 3?

Comment: @Honey The bug report says that `[1, 2] == [1, 2]` used to compile in Swift 3, but I haven't verified that for myself.

Comment: Your code works for me in Xcode 9.3...

Comment: Slight pedantic nitpick: `[[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2 ,4]]` is not a multidimensional array – it's a nested array (true multidimensional arrays enforce that the dimensions are of consistent sizes).

Comment: Checking `contains` against an `Array` like that leads this to have `O(N^2)` performance :(

Comment: @Alexander yes. But I don't know of a better way to remove dups. `[Int]` not hashable...meaning you can't do something like `let removedDups =  Array(Set(originalArray))`. Is there a better way?

Comment: @Honey As others said, update to Swift 4.1. `[Int]` becomes hashable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Are arrays equatable? Can I compare them using `==`

Prior to Swift 4.1, `Array` didn't conform `Equatable`. There was however an overload of `==` that compared two arrays with `Equatable` elements, which is what enabled this to compile:

```
if ["1", "2"] == ["1", "2"] { // using <T : Equatable>(lhs: [T], rhs: [T]) -> Bool
    print("true")
}
```

However in Swift 4.1 (available with Xcode 9.3), `Array<Element>` now conforms to `Equatable` when its `Element` conforms to `Equatable`. This change [is given in the changelog](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#swift-41):

> ### Swift 4.1
>
> [...]
>
> - [SE-0143](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0143-conditional-conformances.md) The standard library types `Optional`, `Array`, `ArraySlice`, `ContiguousArray`, and `Dictionary` now conform to the `Equatable` protocol when their element types conform to `Equatable`. This allows the `==` operator to compose (e.g., one can compare two values of type `[Int : [Int?]?]` with `==`), as well as use various algorithms defined for `Equatable` element types, such as `index(of:)`.

Your example with `multiDimArr.removeDups()` compiles and runs as expected in 4.1, yielding the result `[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4]]`.

In Swift 4.0.3, you could hack it by adding another overload of `removeDups()` for nested arrays:

```
extension Array {
  func removeDups<T : Equatable>() -> [Element] where Element == [T] {

    var result = [Element]()

    for element in self{
      if !result.contains(where: { element == $0 }) {
        result.append(element)
      }
    }

    return result
  }
}

let multiDimArr = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4]]
print(multiDimArr.removeDups()) // [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4]]
```

This does unfortunately lead to some code duplication, but at least you'll be able to get rid of it when updating to 4.1.

The fact that this example doesn't compile in either 4.0.3 or 4.1:

```
if [1, 2] == [1, 2] { // error: Ambiguous use of operator '=='
    print("true")
}
```

is due to the bug [SR-5944](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5944) – the compiler is considering it to be ambiguous due to `==` overloads for `IndexSet` and `IndexPath` (both of which are `ExpressibleByArrayLiteral`). But Swift should default an array literal to `Array` though, resolving the ambiguity.

Saying either:

```
if [1, 2] as [Int] == [1, 2] {
    print("true")
}
```

or not importing `Foundation` resolves the issue.

---

Finally, it's worth noting that the performance of `removeDups()` can be improved if the `Element` type is also `Hashable`, allowing it to run in linear, rather than quadratic time:

```
extension Array where Element : Hashable {

  func removeDups() -> [Element] {
    var uniquedElements = Set<Element>()
    return filter { uniquedElements.insert($0).inserted }
  }
}
```

Here we're using a set to store the elements that we've seen, omitting any that we've already inserted into it. This also allows us to use `filter(_:)`, [as @Alexander points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50275692/remove-duplicates-from-a-multi-dimensional-array/50277004#comment87571171_50277004).

And [in Swift 4.2](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#swift-42), `Array` also conditionally conforms to `Hashable` when its `Element` is `Hashable`:

> ### Swift 4.2
>
> [...]
>
> - [SE-0143](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0143-conditional-conformances.md) The standard library types `Optional`, `Array`, `ArraySlice`, `ContiguousArray`, `Dictionary`, `DictionaryLiteral`, `Range`, and `ClosedRange` now conform to the `Hashable` protocol when their element or bound types (as the case may be) conform to `Hashable`. This makes synthesized `Hashable` implementations available for types that include stored properties of these types.

Comment: And you can use `filter` :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/46354989/3141234

Comment: @Hamish I need same functionality for Swift 3.0 so what i need to changes

Comment: OMG! Hamish, you just saved me hours of coding!!! How can I donate to your cause? :)

Comment: @ItsMeDom Happy to be of help! I don't have a place where you can donate, but you're welcome to upvote the answer if you feel it was useful :)

Comment: @hamish: I did upvote then :) Just one question to the last code block ( beginning with >>extension Array where Element : Hashable {<<): Is it correct that the result is not necessarily ordered like the original array?

Comment: @ItsMeDom No, it preserves the order of the original array, because it uses `filter` which iterates sequentially through an array.

Comment: Thanks @Hamish. You're the best!

Answer (score -2):

This is a place where recursion would solve the problem. Have you considered recursion? I was going to answer the question with actual code, but I don't know the syntax for Swift. so, here is some pesudocode:

```
function removeDupes() {
    buffer = array;
    foreach this->elements as key => element {             
         if(element is type array) {
              this->elements[key] = element->removeDupes();
         } else {
              if(!this->contains(element)) {
                  buffer->add(element);
              }
         }             
    }
    return buffer;
}
```

Basically, you want to test if the element itself is an array. If it is, then you want to call that array's removeDupes() method (which in turn will look for duplicates, unless it finds another array, then it will call itself again).

Comment: I'm **not** asking for psuedocode. Problem is Array of `Int`s not being `Equatable`...